# Comparing string data received from a socket in C

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I have a question on sockets.  I have this code:

```
while(bytes = recv(sClient, cClientMessage, 599, 0)){
```

This puts the message it recives into cClientMessage and the message is always "Message".  How I made an if statement like `if(cClientMessage == "Message"){//do func}`.  Now this code will not do the function I want.  I think this is because it's not receiving the message right.  Can someone help me?

Comment: No idea why this was voted down..

Comment: The accepted solution has some bugs in it, and also there are some bugs not mentioned that appear in the original question. Please see my solution below. (Example: If you receive "Message5" it will be a match even know it shouldn't be).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
if( strcmp( cClientMessage, "Message")) == 0 ) {
   // do something
}
```

**Edit, following suggestion from strager:**

A better solution, which does not depend on the received data being null terminated is to use memcmp:

```
if( memcmp( cClientMessage, "Message", strlen( "Message") )) == 0 ) {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking more memcpy if the \0 is not present, but I guess this may work.

Comment: memcmp, rather than memcpy I think?

Comment: +1 for the clear exposition of the asked question. Bondy's point about the socket usage is important, however.

Comment: The memcmp is unnecessary. "Message" is null terminated so the strcmp will never test more than 8 characters of data. If you know cClientMessage is guarenteed to longer than 8 characters, there is no need for memcmp. (Premature optimization, I know.)

Comment: I think strncmp would be preferable to memcmp.  Also, you're not checking if the message is shorter than 8 characters -- you might get false positives if you received the 4 bytes "Mess", e.g., and your buffer already head "...age\0" in it.

Comment: This has a bug in it if you receive something that is a superset of what you are comparing to. Please see my solution.

Comment: Thank you very Much struggled for about 4 hours before I found the solution with this input

Answer (score 2):

First there is a bug in the code you wrote:

```
while(bytes = recv(sClient, cClientMessage, 599, 0)){
```

This is wrong because recv will return non zero if there is a socket error and your code will lead to an infinite loop.  In particular you want to check for > 0

```
char cClientMessage[599];
while((bytes = recv(sClient, cClientMessage, sizeof(cClientMessage), 0)) > 0)
{
  if(strlen("Message") == bytes && !strncmp("Message", cClientMessage, bytes))
  {
    //cClientMesssage contains "Message"
  }
} 

if(bytes == 0)
{
  //socket was gracefully closed
}
else if(bytes < 0)
{
  //socket error occurred
}
```

The problem with what you did: cClientMessage == "Message"  is that if you compare a char* to a string literal, or a char[] to a string literal, then you will be comparing the pointer addresses and not the actual content.

Comment: The memset is wasteful. Just say cClientMessage[bytes] = 0; bytes will always range from 0 to 598 based on the parameters to recv.

Comment: You should use strncmp instead of strcmp. Also, you're not checking if the message is shorter than 8 characters -- you might get false positives if you received the 4 bytes "Mess", e.g., and your buffer already head "...age\0" in it.

Comment: joe: with strcmp you need the memset on the whole buffer as I had it.  I changed to strncmp though to avoid the memset altogether.